# How do I display a widget ( Loading 20%,30%) while uploading an image flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, file-upload

Im working with the library  multipart_request 0.3.1 to upload images, I have response in the console log (progress from response object 50,51,52,etc) it's perfect

How i do to show a widget animated (Text or StatusBar or ProgressBar)  with the following value "Uploading: 10,11,12,..,100, Complete",

I should set the SetState to the value of the response but I don't know...Thank you in advance

It's my code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:multipart_request/multipart_request.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String imagePath = "";
  var showw = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Pick an image"),
                onPressed: () async {
                  File imagen =
                      await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                  imagePath = imagen.path;
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Call multipart request"),
                onPressed: () {
                  sendRequest();
                },
              ),
              Text("Uploading: " + showw)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  sendRequest() {
    var request = MultipartRequest();

    request.setUrl("http://192.168.1.50/apiphp/api_imagenes.php");
    request.addFile("userImage[]", imagePath);

    Response response = request.send();

    response.onError = () {
      print("Error");
    };

    response.onComplete = (response) {
      print(response);
    };

    response.progress.listen((int progress) {
      print("progress from response object " + progress.toString());
      //var showw = progress.toString();
      //return showw;
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
I use official example to demo this case 
You can do `setState` in `response.onComplete` and `response.progress.listen` 
code snippet

```
Text(showw),
...
response.onComplete = (response) {
      setState(() {
        showw = "Complete";
      });

      print(response);
    };

response.progress.listen((int progress) {
  print("progress from response object " + progress.toString());
  setState(() {
    showw = "Uploading ${progress.toString()}";
  });
});
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:multipart_request/multipart_request.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String imagePath = "";
  String showw = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Pick an image"),
                onPressed: () async {
                  File image =
                  await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                  imagePath = image.path;
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Call multipart request"),
                onPressed: () {
                  sendRequest();
                },
              ),
              Text(showw),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void sendRequest() {
    var request = MultipartRequest();

    request.setUrl("https://b804ca15.ngrok.io/images");
    request.addFile("image", imagePath);

    Response response = request.send();

    response.onError = () {
      setState(() {
        showw = "Complete";
      });
    };

    response.onComplete = (response) {
      setState(() {
        showw = "Complete";
      });

      print(response);
    };

    response.progress.listen((int progress) {
      print("progress from response object " + progress.toString());
      setState(() {
        showw = "Uploading ${progress.toString()}";
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.